# Can a container with STATUS "Exited (-1)" be fixed?

Tags: docker

As a result I can't seem to start it or attach to it:

```
$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
17d34ecd8c24        ubuntu:latest        "bash"              2 hours ago         Exited (-1) 27 minutes ago                        fervent_kowalevski  
...

$ sudo docker start 17d34ecd8c24
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 17d34ecd8c24: [8] System error: Unit docker-17d34ecd8c24ffcc9392735710b56ee9bab1cc62237f152114017fe6f92c3fcb.scope already exists.
FATA[0000] Error: failed to start one or more containers

$ sudo docker attach 17d34ecd8c24
FATA[0000] You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
```

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Did you try restarting the Docker daemon already?

Comment: actually i had not but that's a great suggestion. that being said, it didn't work either :(. I should also mention that I did try to issue "stop" for the container as well but no luck either...

Comment: How did you end up with the ``17d34ecd8c24`` container ? This might able "debugging" the rest of the errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this be related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7015? Check out comment https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7015#issuecomment-52522196 for a workaround.

For your particular error, you would do something like:

```
$ systemctl stop docker-17d34ecd8c24ffcc9392735710b56ee9bab1cc62237f152114017fe6f92c3fcb.scope
```

Then try to start the container again. However, if you were running this container as a bash shell interactively, you won't be able to start it and then attach to it, as the shell will immediately exit. You will need to add `-a` (attach) and `-i` (interactive) to the `docker start` command.

Comment: I had to remove the offending container as there seemed to be a memory leak somewhere, so I can't test this out. But the symptoms describe resemble mine a lot, and so the workaround is a good lead!